# Tiny white insects in the soil-eating roots?

Tags: identification, pests

I notice a lot of white tiny tiny insect in the soil if my plants. They mainly stay in the soil, nothing on the stem or leaves.

I just noticed these things today, so not sure how long they have been living there.

Are they harmless?

Thank you.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Termites..?? Not sure though..

Comment: Could this be soil mite? They are not in every pot, the one that I grow spring onion in doesn't have any. They like pepper, which is slightly worrying. Thank you.

Comment: Most probably yes, i suspect so, but they are soooo tiny that I can't say for sure. Maybe somebody can identify. Oh..you should edit the second picture into your question instead of posting it as an answer.